# Completion Suggester within categories

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create an auto complete feature that generates suggestions within a category. As an example, I want to suggest 'hotels' within 'Amsterdam' and not get suggestions for any other cities.

Is it possible to do this with Elastic Search with Completion Suggester? I don't see an option to 'categorize' name_suggestions.